# Convert ASCII to contour shapefile

Tags: python, python-3.x, contour, shapefile, geopandas

Is there a way to convert ASCII files or numpy arrays directly to contour lines and export as a shapefile (with e.g. geopandas)? For example raster elevation data.

What I normally do is loading ASCII's into python as numpy arrays and store the meta data in a variable. After performing some calculations I export the numpy array as an ASCII along with the meta data and then convert it into a contour map in QGIS. I'm curious if there is a way to perform this all in Python. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: It would help to know if your file is, for example, an ASCII GRID file or a XYZ triplets file. Knowing that the solution is trivial using `gdaldem` in Python.

Comment: It is just an ASCII GRID file that I generated myself by exporting a numpy array and adding a header which can be read by a GIS program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting an ASCII GRID file to a shapefile of contours can be accomplished with the GDAL utility `gdal_countour`

> https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html

For example,

```
gdal_contour -a elev dem.asc contour.shp -i 10.0
```

...that would create 10-meter contours from the DEM data in dem.asc and produce a shapefile in contour.shp|shx|dbf with the contour elevations in the `elev` attribute.

About calling the utility from Python, since GDAL 2.1, GDAL and OGR utilities can be used as library functions, more info here:

> http://erouault.blogspot.com/2015/10/gdal-and-ogr-utilities-as-library.html

and there is even on GDAL trunk a `gdal_countour` test using Python bindings, where you can take a look on how to call the utility programmatically in Python:

> https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_contour.py

Comment: Great, I will create a minimal reproducible example when I have time!